# Display formatted Rich text in browser based infopath form 2010

Tags: infopath, forms-services

I have a Custom Sharepoint List which has a column of type "Enhanced rich text (Rich text with pictures, tables, and hyperlinks). I have done some formatting to the values like making some text Bold, Font coloring and underlining some text.

I have a browser based Infopath 2010 form (Forms Services) which connects to the custom list to display the data in the browser.

I want to show the formatted text in the browser based infopath form with the same formatting as it was in the Sharepoint List. I tried using the textbox control which shows the Sharepoint list data with HTML tags(since the list item is formatted). I also read some forums post which says  browser based forms does not support rich text formatting.

Does Rich text control show formatted text in broswer? If not is there any work around?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution here. This is what i'm exactly looking for. http://www.bizsupportonline.net/infopath2007/how-to-programmatically-get-set-xhtml-rich-text-infopath.htm

Comment: +1 for your question but I was wondering if it is possible have non-code solution.

Comment: Hi Jack, I couldn't find a non-code solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Rich Text Box control.

Comment: Hi John, the rich text control shows the format tool bar when cursor is placed on it. But it doesn't show the formatting that was applied to the list item.

Answer (score 0):

I recently got into similar problem. I too wanted a no-code solution.
What I did ? I have Nintex Workflow in rescue. I created another multi line text field. Designed a workflow to get the inner xml of the infopath form field and copied it in the multi line field. Then using SSRS I referred the multi line field, which has html tags and everything in reports. That's it.

Thanks
Rajdeep